# mySQL create an INSERT stored procedure of unknown number of values

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli, sql-injection

In my mySQL DB I've created an API for using the DB from outside using stored procedure.

I've a decalre a special user for this mission that have only EXECUTE permission - in order to prevent SQL Injections.

I have a table of user's id's connection and i need to create a procedure with unknown number of parameters in it - the procedure should insert all the id's he received into the table.

for now i'm using PHP with mysqli and i'm creating the query my self - which is very unsafe - and it looks like this:

```
/**
 * Add new rows to the invited users tables
 * @param $invitingUser string the inviting user facebook's Id
 * @param $invitedUsers array the invited users facebook's Id
 */
function addInvitedUsers($invitingUser, $invitedUsers)
{
    //check if all the parameters are set
    if (isset($invitingUser) && isset($invitedUsers))
    {
        //create the basic query for insert
        $query = "Insert Into Invited_Users (Inviting_id,Invited_Id) Values ";
        //for each invited users - add it to the query
        foreach($invitedUsers as $invitedUser)
            $query . "('$invitingUser','$invitedUser') ";

        if ($this->queryDb($query));
            echo "added new invited users";
    }
    //if parameters are not set - message
    else
        echo "parameters can't be null";
}
```

i want to create a procedure that will give me the same ability..

i do know that i can't send array or undefined number of parameters to a stored procedure, but i'm sure that there is other way i can the same ability in a safe mode..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to pass and use multiple values to a MySql stored procedure. Your best bet is to pass a comma delimited string of values and then split it inside your SP and MySql doesn't provide means for that out of box.

That being said I believe what you actually need is [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). It's fast and it's safe.

```php
function addInvitedUsers($invitingUser, $invitedUsers)
{
    //check if all the parameters are set
    if (isset($invitingUser) && isset($invitedUsers))
    {
        // create a prepared statement for insert
        $query = "INSERT INTO Invited_Users (Inviting_id, Invited_Id) VALUES (?, ?)";
        $stmt = $this->prepare($query); // you need to implement prepare method in your class
        // bind parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $invitingUser, $invitedUser);
        //for each invited user execute insert
        foreach($invitedUsers as $invitedUser) {
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                echo "added a new invited user";
            }
        }
    }
    //if parameters are not set - message
    else
        echo "parameters can't be null";
}
```

You can obviously encapsulate your insert into a sp and use prepared statement to call it

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE addInvitedUser(IN invitingUser INT, IN invitedUser INT)
  INSERT INTO Invited_Users (Inviting_id, Invited_Id) 
  VALUES (invitingUser, invitedUser);
```

and then in your function just change

```php
$query = "INSERT INTO Invited_Users (Inviting_id, Invited_Id) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

to

```php
$query = "CALL addInvitedUser (?, ?)";
```